# How to perform remote migrations without exposing a port?

Tags: postgresql, migration, docker

I have some SQL migration scripts and my migration tool allows me to specify a remote target which works fine.

My concern is having to expose a port to the production database server. Normally I wouldn't expose a port, instead our API app accesses the database through a Docker network.

My question is firstly, is this a valid concern (exposing a port), and if so, what are the alternative options?

Comment: Exposing a port is not a concern; not having proper authentication or DOS protection is a concern. Having said that, VPNs have been invented for a reason.

Comment: Exposing a port is a valid concern if you have never taken security very seriously thus far, relying on the firewall to protect you.

Comment: The obvious alternative would be to run your migration scripts through the docker network.  Presumably you have thought of this, so it is unclear what your question is.  If the obvious thing worked, you wouldn't be here, so why did it not work?

Comment: @jjanes I'm looking for the standard, correct way to do this, not being a DBA myself. Putting the migration tool on the server introduces other security issues. mustaccio's answer sounds right to me, use a VPN.